# Given a system of linear equations, how do I determine the geometry of them? What determines if the system is in $2$-space vs $3$-space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

For example:

> What does the equation $x + y + z = 2$ represent geometrically?

To which the answer is that it has $1$ pivot and $2$ free variables, so this is a plane in $\Bbb{R}^3$, a $2$ dimensional surface.

I don't quite understand this, what is $\Bbb{R}^3$?

Does the number of equations represent the number of planes?

What determines whether the system of linear equations is in $2$-space or $3$-space?

See the photos for examples:

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYlzy.jpg)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0lrA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{R}^3=\{(x,y,z):x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}\}$

For example $(1,2,3) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ since it is of length $3$ and each entry is a real number.

$(1,2)\not \in \mathbb{R}^3$ since its length is only $2$. $(1,2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Each non-trivial equation describes a plane, but usually when we write multiple equations together, we are interested in their intersection.

Here are some cases of which I encourage you to pick up two pieces of papers, orient it and try to visualize it.

- If two planes are identical, the intersection is the original plane.
- If two planes are parallel and not identical, they do not intersect.
- If two planes are not parallel, they intersect at a line.

Try to play with $3$ pieces of papers as well.

Remark:

- $\{(x,y,z):0=0\}$ is not a plane, is is the whole $\mathbb{R}^3$.